# IOS NSNotification and view lifecycle

Tags: ios, swift, nsnotificationcenter

I have an IOS/Iwatch app which uses notifications to broadcast the reception of a message coming from the watch. My problem is that my notifications are sometimes sent (`NSNotificationCenter`) during the creation of a view that needs to receive it. 
Typically it happens after the `viewDidLoad()` and before the `viewDidAppear()` hooks. I set the Observer in the first hook :

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "sessionDidEnd", name: MRNotifications.CurrentSessionDidEnd.rawValue, object: session.objectID)
}
```

But the view seem to never see the notification. 
Starting from which state in its lifecycle can a View receive a notification ?

Comment: First, you should be sure to call `super` in `viewDidLoad()`.  Second, you can add the observer earlier: in `init`/`init(coder:)`.  Third, how have you verified that the `sessionDidEnd` method is not being called?  Fourth, how have you verified that the `MRNotifications.CurrenSessionDidEnd.rawValue` notification was definitely posted by `session.objectID`?

Comment: To be more clear on my fourth point, when you register for a notification with a non-nil `object` argument, you will only receive the notification if *that* object is the one that posted the notification.

Comment: 1) ok done. 2) Adding earlier would not solve the problem, the notifcation happen just after that (verified by debugger) and before the viewDidAppear() and is not seen . 3) I know this work in normal cycle since I sent the notification later manually when the view is finished to appear and  it works. 4) As I said it works in normal conditions, the notification arriving during the view creation process is not a usual case